# Keepalived - Keep VIP after stop in both nodes

Tags: linux, load-balancing, high-availability, keepalived

There's any way to keep the last VIP configuration in the case of a daemon stop in all the nodes of Keepalived?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I need. Adding the parameter **"-V"** in the file **"/etc/default/keepalived"** keep the VRRP and VIPs on daemon stop. I need this for the configuration changes on our production environment. Thanks!